# Angular 2 routerState outlet is always primary

Tags: angular

I have an app with a primary router-outlet and an auxiliary router-oultet, 
this is my template with both router-outlet's

```html
    <div>
      <!-- links to primary outlet -->
      <a routerLink="/">left 1</a><br>
      <a routerLink="/left2">left 2</a><br>
      <!-- links to right outlet -->
      <a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{right:'right1'}}]">right 1</a><br>
      <a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{right:'right2'}}]">right 2</a><br>
      <a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{right:null}}]">clear right</a><br>
    </div>
    <div style="width:48%;float:left;border:1px solid red;margin-top:20px;padding:2px;">
    <h2>Primary Outlet</h2><hr/>

     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div style="width:48%;float:right;border:1px solid green;margin-top:20px;padding:2px;">
    <h2>Right Outlet</h2><hr/>
    <router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

this is my route definitions

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path : "",
    component : Left1
  },
  {
    path : "left2",
    component : Left2
  },
  {
    path : "right1",
    outlet:'right',
    component : Right1
  },
  {
    path : "right2",
    outlet:'right',
    component : Right2
  }
]
```

In the app component I attached a listener to `router.events` and I would like to know on which outlet is handling the current navigation.

```js
export class App {
  private evtSub;
  constructor(router:Router){
   this.evtSub = router.events.subscribe(e=>{
     //I assume this would log the current routes outlet, but it always logs 'primary'
     console.log("router.routerState.root.outlet is::", router.routerState.root.outlet);
     if(e instanceof RoutesRecognized){
       //this would sure log the current route since we are on the route event, but still no luck
       console.log("RoutesRecognized outlet is ::",e.state.root.outlet);
     }
   })
  }
}
```

the problem is that `routerState.root.outlet` is always 'primary' even if the current route is 'right'

(I tried to listen in child components and in the module and I always get the same behavior)

Here is a plunker with the above behavior https://plnkr.co/edit/csIWByyMSziTaAgmhTuC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ActivatedRoute** to listen to current route.

```
constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute){}
....

console.log(this.actRoute.outlet.toString());
```

By using above you will get current activated router outlet name.

---

**EDIT:** Check it in right1 component

```
@Component({
  selector : "right1",
  template : "this is right1"
})
export class Right1{

  constructor(router:Router, route:ActivatedRoute){
    console.log("Right1 route.outlet (ActivatedRoute) is:",route.outlet);

  }
}
```

Comment: This will also always show "primary", I added it to the above plunker

Comment: Check in Right1 component

Comment: In the right1 component it's indeed right, ands its always 'right' even when routing in the primary outlet, is there any way to know on any navigation which outlet it will affect?

Comment: I am not sure but additionally, you can try this - `console.log(this.route.pathFromRoot.toString());` or `this.children = this.route.snapshot.children,    
        this.children.forEach(child => console.log((child.url[0] || {path:''}).path));`

Comment: I found that by hooking on to the router-outlet's (activate) Output (evt), I can act specifically when this outlet is targeted. `<router-outlet (activate)="primaryOutletActivate($event)"></router-outlet>`